# Failed to run sudo killall python from php script in raspberry pi 2 ver B

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

i run script python from php in my raspberry pi and i wanna stop the program.

when i run program with php is running perfectly but when i run another file php to stop the program i failed.

this my code to run file python using php

```
<?php
shell_exec("/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/python_project/multiple.py");
```

this my code to stop program

```
<?php
shell_exec("usr/bin/sudo killall python");
echo "kill executed"
```

thanks

Comment: This will wait for password input unless you specified `NOPASSWD` in your `sudoers`

Comment: but when i run script python with php was fine? i dont change anything in my sudoers

Comment: I don't see any errors launching the python, but calling `/usr/bin/sudo` **will** wait for password input (plus, you forgot a `/` when calling sudo)

Comment: i try to kill it with their PID using python program then later i use it php to run that script. i get error that said there is no module named psutil

Answer (score 0):

A few problems were identified

1) www-data may not be in your sudoers file, check it is present, if not, add the line

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

to the file.

2) You are missing a "/" from the line "usr/bin/sudo", you should add it to be "/usr/bin/sudo" so the path is correct. usr/bin/sudo does not exist.

Comment: isn't it a security issue to allow root rights for www-data?